# Multiple Workflow 4.5

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I have been using two workflows. "OrderWorkflow" is my main workflow in "OrderWorkflow" am calling another workflow "OrderWF" now when i am loading "OrderWF" it is showing error as ---'OrderWF' is not of type 'OrderWorkflow'. When loading this instance you must ensure that the activity with name 'OrderWF' implements 'OrderWorkflow'. Below is my code

```
    public static void LoadExistingOrder(
        Guid orderId, string status, string value)
    {                       

        WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(new OrderWF());

        var store = CreateInstanceStore();

        app.InstanceStore = store;

        app.Completed = (workflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nWorkflowApplication has Completed in the {0} state.", workflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs.CompletionState);
        };

        app.Unloaded = (workflowApplicationEventArgs) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WorkflowApplication has Unloaded\n");
        };

        app.PersistableIdle = (e) =>
        {
            return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
        };


        app.Load(orderId);//getting error here

        app.ResumeBookmark(status, value);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting the `WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid)` method to do something else than what it is actually doing.

The `.Load(Guid)` method load a previously persisted instance of the workflow the be reloaded in memory, and resumes its flow. It does not load a workflow of another type, and starts that.

Basically what your code does, is create a workflowapplication object with a workflow instance of type `OrderWF`, creates and attaches a store, and tries to resume the workflow with the given guid value `orderId`.

I'm suspecting that the workflow that you are trying to resume is of type `OrderWorkflow`, not of type `OrderWF`.